# What happens if a C2DM or GCM Receiver's onReceive function fails during a Registration Intent?

Tags: android, android-c2dm, android-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

if a C2DM or GCM Receiver's onReceive function fails during a registration intent for some crazy reason, like some exception is raised or the phone is powered off or whatever, can I count on Android replaying that registration intent? otherwise I can't see how I can guarantee that the phone will remain registered for notifications if that function fails unexpectedly...

Answer (score 0):

> can I count on Android replaying that registration intent?

No, you will have to handle that case in your app.

> otherwise I can't see how I can guarantee that the phone will remain
>   registered for notifications if that function fails unexpectedly...

Just try registering again. If registration fails you will be notified, plus you won't have a registration id.

Comment: If Android is refreshing the registration id on its own, then how do I know to try registering again?

Comment: You will be notified that the registration failed.

Comment: Are you certain? I don't see any description of this situation for any of the registration error codes listed in http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html.. what error code do I get back in this case?

Comment: Two things can happen: you get a registration id and everything is ok or you don't get a registration id and you have an error. In the case of an error you need to handle the error properly. Google won't retry anything, you need to handle each situation.